# does statsmodels support multi-level modeling for classifiers

Tags: python, scikit-learn, multilevel-analysis, statsmodels

I have searched and searched the statsmodels documentation for a useable multilevel classifier but have not found any at all. sklearn also provides no support for hiearchical classification models. Is there just no support for models with multiple levels (i.e., multiple intercepts, random effects, etc.) for classifiers in python?

Comment: Statsmodels does offer the generalised linear mixed effect models (https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/mixed_glm.html). Hierarchy isn't implemented yet, but random intercepts and slopes are. The logit model can do classification.

Comment: @CloseToC maybe I'm dumb, what is the difference between hiearchy and random intercepts and slopes?

Comment: What I understand by hierarchical models is that in addition to making parameters random, ie assume they come from a distribution, you can model a shift in the mean of this distribution. For eg intercepts, statsmodels currently allows  $\alpha_i \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$ but not yet something like  $\alpha_i \sim N(\tau + \tau_1 X_i, \sigma^2)$. In the linear mixed model of statsmodels, you can already do that, just not, apparently in the GLM.

Answer (score 1):

You can currently fit multilevel binomial and Poisson models in Statsmodels using the *BayesMixedGLM classes.  They allow arbitrary levels of nesting for both intercepts and slopes, and you can always specify whatever conditional mean structure you want.  The main restriction that I am aware of is that all random effects must be independent of each other.

On a side note, I'm not sure that these models are very useful as "classifiers" (but maybe I just don't know what you mean by that term).  These models are useful for modeling data that have a complex sampling structure in a way that accounts for the resulting statistical dependencies.  This is mainly useful when you have an argument that hinges on knowing how precisely you have estimated a parameter, when the parameter estimate is obtained from data with a complex sampling structure.  It is not necessarily a superior tool for making predictions.

Comment: sorry, by classifier i mean that the output variable is binary or multinomial but not continuous.